# Second Nova MW3 not found by primary

Tags: wifi-configuration, mesh-networking

I have a [Tenda Nova MW3](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tenda-Nova-MW3-Whole-System/dp/B07HGDC7FJ/ref=sr_1_5?adgrpid=57557386040&dchild=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA2uH-BRCCARIsAEeef3mGbfdqDyMH_R-FMgPMkiOqqSMsNj4UUeH8LW2wx2DQ5C8GQMWmRg0aAlbiEALw_wcB&hvadid=267844824457&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9050373&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=15419975887821932410&hvtargid=kwd-460740052755&hydadcr=25458_1819751&keywords=tenda%20nova%20mw3&qid=1608050444&sr=8-5&tag=googhydr-21) wired to my router and functioning just fine. Until recently, I had a second in the room above and it has been acting as a mesh node for at least a year without problems.

Having a re-arrange, I needed to move the second Nova to a different power socket in the same room.

Going through the connecting instructions I do this:

1. Plug Nova in to power
2. Launch app
3. Click: Settings > Add nova
4. Scan QR code on second nova with app
5. App shows: Connecting... Please wait.
6. App eventually shows: "Failed to add."

The light on the second Nova shows:

1. Solid Green (when first plugged in)
2. Flashing Green
3. Eventual Solid Red

The FAQ page tells me that:

1. Solid Green - Connected successfully to primary unit
2. Flashing Green - Searching for connection
3. Solid Red - Failed to connect

Suspecting the second Nova is faulty, I ordered a new one, same model. Going through the same instructions as above I have the same result on the new Nova.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turned out that all I needed to do was press the reset button on the nova for 5 seconds and wait with the Tenda app open on my phone. Both the new and old add-on nodes found the primary node, connected and acted as a mesh. It just took a lot longer for this to happen than I expected.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. You just waited with the app open on its "homepage"? No need to "Add nova" at all? In the first moment I thought it worked for me too, but then the solid red light came back again...